# SingleSelectNode in VBScript

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript, xmlnode, selectsinglenode

I have nodes `<EnginesTimesQueues>` and `<NumberOfEngines>`. I need to update the values to 36 and ABC respectively for both the nodes.

```xml
<job>
  <Step number="3340">
    <Category name="Parameters">
      <Item name="EnginesTimesQueues" commarea="Y">6</Item>
    </Category>
  </Step>

  <Step number="3360">
    <Category name="Parameters">
      <Item name="NumberOfEngines" commarea="Y">2</Item>
    </Category>
  </Step>
</job>
```

I am trying to traverse to nodes using `SingleSelectNode()` with nodes as:

```xpath
/Job/Step/Category/Item[@name='EnginesTimesQueues']|/Job/Step/Category/Ite[@commarea='Y']
/Job/Step/Category/Item[@name='NumberOfEngines']|/Job/Step/Category/Item[@commarea='Y']
```

Initially in loop its updating EnginesTimesQueues value to 36 and second time instead of updating to NumberOfEngines to 'ABC', it is again updating EnginesTimesQueues to 'ABC'.

Comment: Please show your (VBScript) code and the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
Select objNodeList = objDoc.DocumentElement.Selectnodes("/Job/Step/")
objNodeList.Item(0).SelectSingleNode("/Category/Item[@name='EnginesTimesQueues']|/Category/Item[@commarea='Y']").Text = "36" 
objNodeList.Item(1).SelectSingleNode("/Category/Item[@name='NumberOfEngines']|/Category/Item[@commarea='Y']").Text = "ABC"
```

Updating the answer with another solution. this Xpath should also work. Give it a try.
/Job/Step[1]/Category/Item[@name='NumberOfEngines']|/Job/Step[1]/Category/Item[@commarea='Y']

By default the vbscript will consider the the first occurrence of 'Step' as its track to traverse. We need to explicitly specify the node index to access the specific ones.

Note: I haven't run this code at my end. You may need some debugging.

Comment: Hi Mithilesh, Thanks for the response.

I have tried with Step[1] but it is not able to traverse to the path. I am getting an error saying 'Invalid Node'

Comment: Can you please try this and let me know the result 
/Job/Step[position()=2]/Category/Item[@name='NumberOfEngines']|/Job/Step[position()=2]/Category/Item[@commarea='Y']

Remember, positions always starts from 1 and not from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that the method name is `SelectSingleNode()`, not `SingleSelectNode()`, and that XPath expressions are case-sensitive (hence `/Job` won't match a node `<job>`): you're using [**union**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx#Example%20of%20Unions%20(%20|%20)) expressions, meaning that

```
/Job/Step/Category/Item[@name='NumberOfEngines']|/Job/Step/Category/Item[@commarea='Y']
```

will match `<Item>` nodes whose `name` attribute has the value "NumberOfEngines" **as well as** `<Item>` nodes whose `commarea` attribute has the value "Y". Since the latter (sub)expression matches both `<Item>` nodes, and `SelectSingleNode()` restricts the result to a single item, you're getting the first node again.

If you want to match two attributes of a node at the same time use the `and` operator:

```
/Job/Step/Category/Item[@name='NumberOfEngines' and @commarea='Y']
```